# How to use Libudev to find out which ports are connected to my Usb

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, udev, serial-port

I made a kind of module. Different sensors are placed in the module. I connected the module to Raspberry Pi through RS232 converter. I am using Libudev to automatically find out which Pi port has RS232 converter using Vendor Id and Product Id and reading data from it successfully and displaying it on front-end. Now my problem is that I have two modules now and both are connected with same Pi and both RS232 Vendor id and Product id are same . In front end I have made an option to select module 1 or 2. How do I differentiate between both converters aside from Vendor id and Product id. It would be best if the solution can be provided through Libudev.
P.S : Currently Libudev detects the most recent port I plugged the RS232 converter in.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is to make the name of the device node of the RS232 converters, e.g. `/dev/ttyUSB0`, a *parameter* to your application. Via commandline options, via a configuration file, or otherwise.

Because your application may run on some other machine, with lots of other RS232 converters with same vendor and product id, but without your module connected to any of them. Then it will be *necessary* for the user to choose which RS232 converters your application should use, and if he doesn't have a way to set this, your application won't work on his machine.

As for automatically distinguishing between USB devices with same vendor and product it, you could look at the serial number (if it is different, some devices have no serial number, or always the same one). You can also look at the USB port path the devices are connected to. You can use `udev` rules to make symlinks with known names for those devices, and use those names as defaults for the above parameters.

Comment: I cannot distinguish between physical paths because what if there is a Usb port connected with my Pi Board. I cannot differentiate through /dev/ttyUSB0 because they keep changing. I cannot differentiate through Bus Ids. It has no serial number though :(

Comment: You certainly can differentiate between physical paths. Try `lsusb -t`, and look at the paths in `/sys`. And you can differentiate through `/dev/ttyUSB0` with proper `udev` rules, which will assign names which won't change.

Comment: Can the solution be anything other than physical path because I have already tried that and I am facing a lot of issues when I connect more than 2 modules. So I want it to be other than physical paths